# Delta rule neural network teaching. Algorithm explanation necessary

Tags: algorithm, neural-network

I'm doing a research, a project on neural networks. Just for myself. Earlier I've managed to understand a Backpropagation teaching algorithm, its basics, not the whole story, of course. But lots of resources refer to the delta rule, which is a bit special. I've already managed to understand that weights here are modified one by one. But there are a lot of questions. Could you explain me how does it work, but in more approachable way than it's on wikipedia. Just the algorithm, but with a clear explanation of steps and 'how it works'.

---

By the way, there are derivatives used for teaching. Can't understand why.
And yes, no special source code is necessary unless it'll help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overall idea is to treat the neural net as a function of the weights `w_ij`, instead of the inputs:  the goal is to *minimize the error* between the actual outputs and the target outputs in your training data.  For each (input/output) training pair, the delta rule determines the direction you need to adjust `w_ij` to reduce the error for that training pair.  By taking short steps for each training pair, you find a direction which is best for the entire training corpus.

Imagine you are in the middle of a huge, mountainous ski resort which is too complicated to understand all at once -- but if your job is to make it to the bottom, all you need to do is head downhill from where you're standing.  This is called the *gradient descent* method:  find the *steepest way down the slope* from where you are, and take a step in that direction.  Enough steps will see you at the bottom; for a neural net, the "bottom" is a neural net that is a best fit for your training data.

This is why you need the derivative:  the *derivative is the slope*, and it turns out it's easy to compute -- that's your delta rule.  Derivatives are used for teaching because that's how they got the rule in the first place.

For a step-by-step derivation of the delta rule, I'm afraid I can't improve on the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_rule) you refer to.

Comment: Thank you a lot, of course, no step-by-step derivation needed, just explanation.
But what's the huge difference between this rule and a basic Backpropagation method? Only these weights which determine here which way to adjust the whole system? Unfortunately still have problems with the necessity of derivation. Is it just something special for this method?
And a short question, could you give some pros and cons for this rule? Just in general, no need to expand it.

Comment: I can't make it any simpler than that.  The derivative is the gradient.  If you want to do gradient descent, you need the gradient, so you take the derivative.  Backpropagation is exactly the same in this respect, only with multiple layers of neurons.

Comment: Pros:  delta and backpropagation are simple, and they work.  Cons: choosing the arbitrary "learning rate" parameter; also, gradient descent is not the fastest optimization method (e.g., conjugate gradient is faster.  However, it is not simpler, nor does it use less calculus...)

Comment: Yes, It's very clear now, thank you. It seems I need to read more info about this method. Special thanks for pros and cons.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this resource will help you a lot (if you haven't already discovered it) 
http://www.ml-class.org
Here you can find perfect **short** video lectures (15 min or less), some of them about mathematical background and intuitions, which stands behind backpropogation algorithm. Hope it will be usefull.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this resource but didn't pay any attention. Will try to surf through its videos.